# Multinomial Distribution with Selecting Candy from a Bag.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

> Suppose that a “fun-sized” bag of Halloween candy will contain $7$
>   pieces, and that each of the $7$ pieces put into the bag will be equally
>   likely to be brandy, gin, rum, or scotch flavored, independently of
>   what the flavors of the other pieces are. What is the probability that
>   the bag will contain at least $3$ pieces of $2$ different flavors?

So my understanding of the problem is it doesn't matter what you have already selected from the bag. The probability of selecting any of the four flavors will always be $1\over4$. For the criteria to be met, we must have either $3$ pieces of $2$ different flavors and $1$ of the other $2$ flavors, or $4$ pieces of one flavor and $3$ of another.

The probability of getting $3$ pieces of $2$ different flavors and $1$ of the other $2$ flavors:

First select the two flavors to have $3$ pieces: $4\choose 2$

Then select one of the other two flavors to get one piece: $2\choose1$

Then looking at an individual group, we have a probability of $7\choose{3} $$4\choose{3}$ $(1/4)$$^7$

All together, we get $4\choose 2$$2\choose1$$7\choose{3} $$4\choose{3}$ $(1/4)$$^7=.1025$

The probability of getting $4$ pieces of one flavor and $3$ of another:

First select the one flavor to have $4$ pieces: $4\choose1$

Then select the one flavor to have $3$ pieces: $3\choose1$

Then looking at an individual group, we have a probability of $7\choose4$$4\choose3$$(1/4)$$^7$

All together, we get $4\choose1$$3\choose1$$7\choose4$$4\choose3$$(1/4)$$^7=.1025$.

So I have that the probability that the bag will contain at least $3$ pieces of $2$ different flavors is $.1025+.1025=.205$.

I would like to know if I did this correctly and if there is a simpler approach.

Comment: Looks correct to me.  As for if there is a *simpler* approach, I can at least say this is how I'd think to solve it too and no better method jumps out to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight error in the second part of your computation.

There is value in seeing if the problem fits into a widely prevalent one, and solve it thus.
Here it is equivalent to rolling a $4$ faced dice $7$ times.

You might consider standardising the approach,
using the formula **[Choose "faces" (types) to show ] $\times\;$[Permute them]**

Here there are only two possible *patterns*,

$3-3-1-0 \;of\;a\;kind:\;\left[\binom{4}2\binom21 \right] \times[ \frac{7!}{3!3!}] =1680$

$4-3-0-0\;of\;a\;kind:\;\left[\binom{4}1\binom31 \right] \times [\frac{7!}{4!3!}] =420$

Add and divide by $4^7$